# is there a formula like Stewart's theorem for $AI$?

Tags: geometry

suppose $ABC$ is a triangle and $I$ is the incenter. is there a formula like Stewart's theorem for $AI$ ?

something like $\large\frac{bc}{p \cos \left( \frac{A}{2} \right)}$ which $p=(AB+BC+AC)$

Comment: Are you looking for the formula $\space AI=\dfrac{2bc}{b+c}\cos\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right)\space ?$

Comment: @YNK I think that's it. can you prove it for me .

Comment: I apologise for giving a wrong formula for $AI$ in my last comment. I just post the requested proof that includes the correct expression of $AI$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: StewartTheorem]

The required expression for $AI$, where $I$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$ can be derived using the Stewart’s theorem, which is shown in the diagram. It states, that,
$$AG=d^2=\dfrac{b^2n+c^2m}{a}-mn. \tag{1}$$

In our case $AG$ is the angle bisector of $\angle A$. Therefore, according to the angle bisector theorem, we have,
$$m=\dfrac{ab}{b+c}\qquad\text{and}\qquad n=\dfrac{ac}{b+c}.\tag{2}$$

When we substitute, values of $m$, and $n$ from (2) in (1), we get,
$$d^2=\dfrac{b^2c}{b+c}+\dfrac{bc^2}{b+c}-\dfrac{a^2bc}{\left(b+c\right)^2}=\dfrac{bc}{\left(b+c\right)^2}\left(b^2+c^2+2bc-a^2\right)\tag{3}.$$

Now, we express $\cos\left(A\right)$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$ by applying law of cosine to $\triangle ABC$.
$$\cos\left(A\right) = \dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} \tag{4}$$

We substitute (4) in (3) to obtain,
$$d^2=\dfrac{2b^2c^2\left(\cos\left(A\right)+1\right)}{\left(b+c\right)^2}=\dfrac{2b^2c^2 \cos^2\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right)}{\left(b+c\right)^2}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad d=\dfrac{2bc}{b+c}\cos\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right).$$

We know that the angle bisectors of $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ meet at the incenter $I$. Therefore, we can apply the angle bisector theorem to $\triangle ABG$ as shown below to derived the sought formula.
$$AI=\dfrac{bd}{b+m}=\dfrac{\dfrac{2b^2c}{b+c}\cos\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right)}{b+\dfrac{ab}{b+c}}=\dfrac{2bc}{a+b+c}\cos\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

We know $[ABC] = \frac{1}{2}AB \cdot AC \cdot \sin(A) = \frac{r}{2}(AB + AC + BC)$ where $r$ is the inradius, so $r = \frac{AB \cdot AC \cdot \sin(A)}{AB + AC + BC}$. We also know the distance from $A$ to the in-touch point is $\frac{AB + AC - BC}{2}$, so using Pythagoras' Theorem, we get
\begin{align*}
AI^2 &= \left (\frac{AB + AC - BC}{2}\right )^2 + \left (\frac{AB \cdot AC \cdot \sin(A)}{AB + AC + BC}\right )^2\\
&= \frac{(AB + AC)^2 - BC^2 + 4AB^2 \cdot AC^2 \cdot \sin^2(A)}{4(AB + AC + BC)^2}
\end{align*}
I don't see this simplifying further.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the prpendiculars $IB_1$ and $IC_1$ from $I$ to the sides $AC$ and $AB$ respectively. It is well-known that $AB_1=AC_1=s-a$ where $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ is the semi-perimeter. From the right triangle $\triangle AIB_1$ we read:
$$AI=\frac{AB_1}{\cos\frac A2}=\frac{b+c-a}{2\cos \frac A2}\tag1$$
On the other hand, from the law of cosines $\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$ we get
$$2\cos^2\frac A2=\frac{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)}{2bc}\tag2$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can find
$AI$ in terms of side lengths or we can derive YNK's formula again.